# Filter text layers using selectedLayers property

Tags: extendscript

I am trying to put a check on type of layer to ensure my function call only applies to a text layer in selected layers (number of selected layers are several hundreds). It seems I am doing some mistake using the typeOf method. Can someone please help?

```
var myComp = app.project.activeItem;
var selectedLayers = myComp.selectedLayers;
var numLayers = selectedLayers.length;

    for(var i=0; i < numLayers; i++){
        var mySourceText = selectedLayers[i].property("ADBE Text Properties").property("ADBE Text Document");
        var myTextDoc = mySourceText.value;
             if (typeOf(selectedLayers[i]) == "TextLayer") {
                mySourceText.setValue(trim(myTextDoc));
            }
     }

function trim(strValue){
    var str = new String(strValue);
    return str.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g,"");
}
```

Comment: Why is the typeOf() function called after you define mySourceText? If it's not a text layer getting mySourceText.value might be throwing an error, and as extendscript seems to fail silently it might not ever get to the typeOf() call.

Comment: My code might be wrong but this is what I am trying to do is that call trim function on  each element of selected layers array if the element (either text or any other layer) is a text layer. I hope you can suggest something to achieve this.

Comment: From array I mean an array at run time as a result of 'i' for next loop in my example.

Comment: Put the `if(typeOf (selectedLayers[i]) == "TextLayer") {` part on the first line of the for() loop, and see how it goes

Comment: If I put this in the simplest terms, I would say to my code please run the "trim" function only on text layers from the selected layers.

Comment: Stib, I gave it a try but getting "Function typeOf is undefined" error.

Answer (score 1):

The correct boolean test you want is

```
if (selectedLayers[i] instanceof TextLayer) {
```

`instanceof`, and no quotes for `TextLayer`.